# append value in between the text in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to add class="value" between iframe and width, I have tried following

```
UPDATE TableName
SET MemoText = CONVERT(nvarchar(max), MemoText) + ' class="value" '
WHERE memotext LIKE '%<iframe width="100%" height="500" "%'
```

This query appends the `class="value"` last, but I have to add `class="value"` between `iframe` and `width`.

Comment: With the Help of Stuff in Sql you can Achieve this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use REPLACE function:

```
UPDATE appointment
SET MemoText = REPLACE(MemoText, 'iframe', 'iframe class="value"')
WHERE memotext like '%<iframe width="100%" height="500" %'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `STUFF` function comes in handy here:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '<iframe width="100%" height="500"' AS col
)

SELECT    
    STUFF(col, PATINDEX('<iframe width="[0-9]', col) + 9, 0, 'class="value" ') AS col_out
FROM yourTable
WHERE col LIKE '%<iframe width="100%" height="500"%';
```

[image]

### Demo

The only trick here worth mentioning in more detail is that if we want to *insert* text using `STUFF`, at an exact position in the string, without replacing anything, then set the stuff length to be zero.

Also note that if you plan to do replacement work on HTML content of any great involvement, you should use a parser, like JavaScript, rather than manually trying to do it.

This answer is preferable to the accepted answer, because the above uses a more targeted replacement.  For example, the accepted answer would replace *all* instances of `iframe`, even the ones which were not followed by a `width` attribute.